# Plotnine's scale fill and axis position

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I would like to move the x-axis to the top of my plot and manually fill the colors. However, the usual method in ggplot does not work in plotnine. When I provide the `position='top'` in my `scale_x_continuous()` I receive the warning: `PlotnineWarning: scale_x_continuous could not recognize parameter 'position'.` I understand position is not in plotnine's scale_x_continuous, but what is the replacement? Also, `scale_fill_manual()` results in an `Invalid RGBA argument: 'color'` error. Specifically, the `value` requires an *array-like* object. Thus I provided the array of colors, but still had an issue. How do I manually set the colors for a scale_fill object?

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *
lst = [[1,1,'a'],[2,2,'a'],[3,3,'a'],[4,4,'b'],[5,5,'b']]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['xx', 'yy','lbls']) 

fill_clrs = {'a': 'goldenrod1',
 'b': 'darkslategray3'}
ggplot()+\
  geom_tile(aes(x='xx', y='yy', fill = 'lbls'), df) +\
  geom_text(aes(x='xx', y='yy', label='lbls'),df, color='white')+\
  scale_x_continuous(expand=(0,0), position = "top")+\
   scale_fill_manual(values = np.array(list(fill_clrs.values())))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotnine does not support changing the position of any axis.

You can pass a `list` or a `dict` of colour values to `scale_fill_manual` provided they are recognisable colour names. The colours you have are obscure and they are not recognised. To see that it works try 'red' and 'green', see https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/named_colors.html for all the named colors. Otherwise, you can also use hex colors e.g. #ff00cc.